# Safely update old version of phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, installation

I'd like to know if it's possible to update phpmyadmin 3.4.1. safely to 3.5.8.2 or even to 4.0.9?

I have a live database which I cannot take offline. I don't have a mirror server.

Comment: phpmyadmin is just accessing the database, and shouldn't require any database changes to update it. But this will be completely dependent on your environment and how things are setup.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an installation taken from phpmyadmin.net, just follow these instructions:
http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#upgrading-from-an-older-version

Otherwise, verify with your distro, they might have specific upgrade instructions. As Steven V said, upgrading phpMyAdmin won't affect MySQL itself.